# How can I solve the (gedit:7404) error in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gedit

When I use `sudo gedit .bashrc`, why do I receive the error below from Ubuntu 16.04?

```
** (gedit:7404): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported
```

Comment: Editing conflict, but what version of Ubuntu *are* you using? 14.04 or 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use kate (a nice GUI editor) instead of gedit.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kate
gksudo kate /path/file.txt`

You can customize kate, and I think you will like it better than gedit.

Comment: Interesting. I might have to try it.